# I can't find my error for my C# maths project

Tags: c#, math

I am making a maths project where I ask the user some questions based on the difficulty level they select!

For the easy level, I ask add, subtract and multiplication questions.
For the normal level, I ask add, subtract, multiplication and division questions.
For the hard level, I ask multiplication, division, power and square root questions.

When the user chooses difficulty level easy and hard it works fine, but when the user chooses normal difficulty it only gives addition question.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace mathstester
{
    class Program
    {
        enum UserDifficulty
        {
            Easy,
            Normal,
            Hard
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string userDifficulty = "";
            do
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What difficulty level would you like to do! Please type E for Easy, N for Normal and H for hard");
                userDifficulty = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            } while (userDifficulty != "E" && userDifficulty != "N" && userDifficulty != "H");

            int numberOfQuestions = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.Write("How many questions would you like to answer? Please type a number divisible by 10!");
                int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out numberOfQuestions);
            } while (numberOfQuestions % 10 != 0);

            int numberOfQuestionsLeft = numberOfQuestions;
            Random random = new Random();
            int score = 0;

            while (numberOfQuestionsLeft > 0)
            {
                var operation = random.Next(1, 7);
                int number1 = 0;
                int number2 = 0;
                switch (userDifficulty)
                {
                    case "E":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(13);
                                number2 = random.Next(13);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "N":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 1:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                    case "H":
                        switch (operation)
                        {
                            case 3:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 4:
                                number1 = random.Next(1000);
                                number2 = random.Next(1000);
                                break;
                            case 5:
                                number1 = random.Next(13);
                                number2 = random.Next(4);
                                break;
                            case 6:
                                number1 = random.Next(100);
                                break;

                        }
                        break;
                }

                if(operation == 1 && userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N")
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} + {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 + number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 2 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} - {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 - number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 3 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N" || userDifficulty == "H"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} * {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 * number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 4 && (userDifficulty == "N" || userDifficulty == "H"))
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} / {number2} =");
                    int correctAnswer = number1 / number2;
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 5 && userDifficulty == "H")
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is {number1} ^ {number2} =");
                    double correctAnswer = Math.Pow(number1, number2);
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
                else if (operation == 6 && userDifficulty == "H")
                {
                    Console.Write($"What is √{number1} =");
                    double correctAnswer = Math.Sqrt(number1);
                    int userAnswer = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    if (correctAnswer == userAnswer)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Well Done!");
                        score++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your answer is incorrect!");
                    }
                    numberOfQuestionsLeft--;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"You got a score of {score} out of {numberOfQuestions}");
        }
    }
}
```

When I choose Normal difficulty:
[image]

Can someone help me spot my mistake?

Thank You!

Comment: Did you try to debug this with the *step debugger* ? If so, where do you think the problem is. If not, then you should

Comment: Yes, I used the debugger but I still didn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
if (operation == 1 && userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N")
```

`&&` takes precedence over `||`. This means it is checking `operation == 1` and `userDifficulty == "E"` first, and then it checks `userDifficulty == "N"` on its own. Since this last condition is always true for your normal difficulty, it will always pick this one (since it's the first option in your code).

To fix it, add parentheses.

```
if (operation == 1 && (userDifficulty == "E" || userDifficulty == "N"))
```

Comment: [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/)

Answer (score 0):

on your condition don't used || (or) be restrict on condition cause it also read other condition used " if(operation == 1 && user Difficulty == "E" )" instead of  XX if(operation == 1 && user Difficulty == "E" || user Difficulty == "N") XX.